# Limit of statically allocated array size in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, architecture

This is a memory-allocation related question in C. I have a number (let's say 5) 2-dimensional arrays of floats. Each of the arrays is 60x60.

Theoretically, this information represents static data that is not going to be changed after it is initially calculated.

Should this be stored as a static size array or is this big enough for being allocated dynamically? I suppose I am unclear about the size of the stack and if declarations such as `arr [60][60]` will be stored exclusively in the `DATA` section. Does this depend on the machine or on the code itself? Since stack memory usually corresponds to high level cache, what is the size limit for this on, let's say Intel i5 line of machines?

I understand that this is very broad question, so I will gladly take references to credible background sources.

Answer (score 1):

So it's 5 times 60 times 60 times 4 (size of `float`)? That's only 72000 bytes. Small enough to declare it as "static" compile-time arrays/matrices, even in quite small embedded systems. And if you're on a normal PC (Windows, Linux, OSX) then the stack is at least a megabyte, maybe as much as 8 MB, so no problem there either. Also, on a reasonable modern computer (i.e. one made the last six-seven years or so) copying of 72000 bytes is still fast enough for you to not notice it.

Comment: Should I worry about "moving" this data later onto a heap? Say for a linear algebra function `do_fancy_math(float * input)`? Is there any actual movement or copying happening in such a case?

Comment: @Manbroski The first thing to remember is that all arrays decays to pointers when passed to a function, so there is really no copying of the actual data. So declaring this as a local variable in `main` and then passing it around will not cause much problems either with space or execution time.

Comment: Thank you. I should have remembered that. +1 for not telling me to RTFM.

Comment: @Manbroski But what you *should* do, is to make some tests and benchmark them to see if the performance (both execution time and storage) is acceptable.